# Objective-C, releasing an object two times?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I recently started learning Objective-C 2.0, with a book, and I want to know if I got this concept right.

So here is the code, which causes an error for releasing an object that was not allocated:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Fraction *aFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction *sum = [[Fraction alloc] init], *sum2;
    int n, i, pow2;

    [sum setTo: 0 over: 1];

    NSLog (@"Enter a value for n");
    scanf ("%i", &n);

    pow2 = 2;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) {
        [aFraction setTo: 1 over: pow2];
        sum2 = [sum add: aFraction];
        [sum release];
        sum = sum2;
        pow2 *= 2;
    }

    NSLog (@"After %i iterations, the sum is %g and the fraction is %i/%i.", n, [sum convertToNum], [sum numerator], sum.denominator);
    [aFraction release];
    [sum release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering about sum and sum2. Here is the method add:

```
- (Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
{
    Fraction *resultFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    int resultNum, resultDenom;
    resultNum = numerator * f.denominator + denominator * f.numerator;
    resultDenom = denominator * f.denominator;

    [resultFraction setTo: resultNum over: resultDenom];
    [resultFraction reduce];

    return resultFraction;
}
```

Let me explain what I think is going on.

For the first iteration of the loop, `sum` is allocated, then I enter the `add:` method, and the `resultFraction` is allocated. It is returned to `sum2`, meaning that resultFraction does not take any memory after being returned.

The first sum, allocated before the loop, is released and `sum = sum2`, meaning that the object "in" `sum2` is now "in" `sum`, and `sum2` does not take any memory after the assignment. Next, a new `resultFraction` is allocated and returned to `sum2`, which is free until now, and so on, until sum is released after exiting the loop.

Now there is just one object (the one returned by `add:`), and it is just being assigned to `sum` / `sum2` (pointers? or ?). However, it is not like I thought it was -- that when `sum2` is being assigned a new object (the one returned by `add:`), and not being released, even after assigning that object to `sum`, the previous one is still there. This means that after n assignments there will be n objects "in" `sum2`. and because of that when I try to release both `sum` and `sum2` before pool drain I get the error. The error is from the second object I try to release, and I just can release *either* `sum` or `sum2`, because they both are connected to the last object returned by the `add:` method?

I hope I was clear enough, because I've been banging my head against the wall all day long, and it just came to me and I really hope I got this right so I can continue with the book. :)

Comment: Do you realize that you have one sentence with 230 words? I'd write an answer, but I'm too busy looking for some aspirin. I do love that your very next line starts: "I hope I was clear enough..." ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What book is that?  That is some distinctly non-standard memory management patterns.

First, this method:

```
- (Fraction *) add: (Fraction *) f
```

Should be returning an auto-released object.  It currently isn't.   This leads to mass confusion on the calling side in that the mantra is no longer "if you want to keep an object return value (beyond NARC), you must retain it".

Next, when you see an expression like `sum = sum2;` (where both variables are object references;  Foo*), that is *exactly* like the expression `x = 5;`.  It is a simple numerical assignment; no retain/release implied.

Thu, if you have:

```
sum = [[Fraction alloc] init];
sum2 = [[Fraction alloc] init];
sum = sum2;
```

You've just leaked the Fraction instance that sum2 was referring to.   So:

- think of retains/releases as deltas; you increase or decrease the count.  As long as your increases are exactly balanced with your decreases, you are doing it right.
- think of the `sum` in `Fraction *sum;` as a *potential reference to an object*.  When declared, it is nothing.  When you assign it to the result of `[[Fraction alloc] init];`, there is no magic -- `sum` just holds the address of the Fraction object in memory.

---

Are you referring to this?

```
    sum2 = [sum add: aFraction];
    [sum release];
    sum = sum2;
```

The `release` releases the old `sum` before overwriting that pointer with a reference to a new object on the next line.

Try build and analyze on that code.  It will produce warnings.  The book is teaching you how to do memory management using a pattern that doesn't leak, but is decidedly not standard.  I'm not convinced that going down that path is useful;  the reality is that you will *always* have autorelease in play and, thus, should *always* follow the standards of the system, even in your own totally isolated code.  Why spend the time learning, then un-learning, a different pattern at this point?  (I'm all for learning different patterns and systems... just not in this context).

Comment: +1 Not that @bbum needs help with memory management from me, but the lack of autorelease in -add: was the first thing that jumped out at me too.

Comment: The book is "Programming in Objective-C 2.0" Second Edition, by Stephen Kochan. I'm still in the first chapters so maybe that's why this "autorelease object" was not used. I have some experience in C and since Objective-C is like it, I noticed some things that should've been done but were not, however they were explained/added later.

As to bbum`s explanations:
1. sum points to x, sum2 to y, next sum points to what sum2 points, so isn't what was in sum leaked?
2. Since sum2 is starting as a pointer and was not increased, I should not be concerned about releasing it?

Comment: I thought that may be the book. I suggest you go to the official site http://www.classroomm.com/objective-c/ for the book. It has plenty of help on each chapter and you can put your code up for peers and Stephen Kochan to look at and help with. One tip by the way is Try not to over complicate or think to far ahead of whats requied for your answers. The first lot of chapters are only looking for simple solutions

Comment: Neat.  If the support community is good, then the dichotomy between the first chapters and reality are probably not an issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I myself thought that this was the case. I guess it's too early to get things especially like that settled down in my head. Furthermore my goal is to become an iOS developer and as of right now I have two more books on the subject. So I guess I`ll go through all of them and then get things settled down in my head. Thanks :)